# Ignore children nodes when searching for regular expression

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I want to identify a splitpoint in a large text document with BeautifulSoup. Therefore, I have formulated a regular expression to find the Tag in which a specific string occurs. The problem is that it does not work if there is further formatting / children nodes within the string I am searching for.

```
t1 = BeautifulSoup("<p class=\"p p8\"><strong>Question-And-Answer</strong></p>")

t2 = BeautifulSoup("<p class=\"p p8\"><strong>Question</strong>-<strong>And</strong>-<strong>Answer</strong></p>")

t1.find(text = re.compile("Question[s]*-And-Answer[s]*", re.IGNORECASE))
>>> 'Question-And-Answer'

t2.find(text = re.compile("Question[s]*-And-Answer[s]*", re.IGNORECASE))
>>> None
```

The output should be the `p` Tag object.

Comment: not sure if this is helpful, but if you do `re.match("Question[s]*-And-Answer[s]*", t2.text).group()`, it'll output your desired result. But like I said, not sure if that helps you moving forward.

Comment: Does my answer below solve the problem? Please let know what is still missing or needs clarifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have here is that the text you are looking for is split with `strong` tags inside the `p` node, and thus the regex search using `text`  argument in `.find` won't work, it is just how it is implemented in BS.

**If you know that the texts are in `p` nodes**, you can use a lambda expression in the `.find` call and run a regex search against `text` property of each `p` tag to find the elements you need:

```
print(t2.find(lambda t: t.name == "p" and re.search(r'Questions*-And-Answers*', t.text)))
# => <p class="p p8"><strong>Question</strong>-<strong>And</strong>-<strong>Answer</strong></p>
```

Note that `[s]` is the same as `s` in a regex.

Comment: The problem with this approach is it will match the full html if it contains the required text. For clarification, try running your code with `<html><body><p class="p p8"><strong>Question</strong>-<strong>And</strong>-<strong>Answer</strong></p></body></html>` as the input.

Comment: @KeyurPotdar If OP only wants to get `p` elements with these texts, then it is possible to solve by adding `t.name == "p"` condition.